# value of type integer cannot be converted to object because integer in not reference type

Tags: arrays, vba, visual-studio, function

```
Module Module1
Sub main()
    Dim pl(), pll() As Integer
    Dim a, b As Integer
    ReDim pl(0)
    ReDim pll(0)
    Do
        a = InputBox("insert number:")
        If a <> 0 Then
            b = b + 1
            ReDim Preserve pl(b)
            pl(b) = a
        End If
    Loop Until a = 0
    pll = **se(pl)**

End Sub
Function se(pol()) As Integer()
    Dim r, t, w, m As Integer
    Dim fix() As Integer
    ReDim fix(0)
    r = UBound(pol)
    w = 2
    For t = 1 To r
        For m = 1 To r
            If w <= r Then
                If pol(w) < pol(t) Then
                    ReDim Preserve fix(t)
                    fix(t) = pol(w)
                End If
            End If
            w = w + 1
        Next
    Next

    se = fix
End Function
```

End Module

Hi, i created this function(dont know if its working) se(pl) that take array of numbers and return that array but in ascending order. But when I want assign that function into array - pll=se(pl) it gives me this error ==> "value of type integer cannot be converted to object because integer in not reference type"

Im sorry im noob, Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adjusted your code to make it work. Yet, I tried to stick as much as possible to the original code to make it easier for you to learn from this solution:

```
Option Base 0
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim pl() As Integer
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer
ReDim pl(0)

Do
    a = InputBox("insert number:")
    If IsNumeric(a) And a <> 0 Then
        b = b + 1
        ReDim Preserve pl(b)
        pl(b) = a
    End If
Loop Until a = vbNullString

Debug.Print "Unsorted:"
For a = LBound(pl) To UBound(pl)
    Debug.Print pl(a)
Next a

se intArray:=pl

Debug.Print "Sorted:"
For a = LBound(pl) To UBound(pl)
    Debug.Print pl(a)
Next a

End Sub
Function se(ByRef intArray() As Integer)

Dim t As Integer, w As Integer, m As Integer

For t = LBound(intArray) To UBound(intArray)
    For m = LBound(intArray) To UBound(intArray)
        If intArray(t) < intArray(m) Then
            w = intArray(t)
            intArray(t) = intArray(m)
            intArray(m) = w
        End If
    Next m
Next t

End Function
```

Some important notes:

(1) If you want to `Dim` multiple variables in one row then you'll have to repeat the `DataType` for each variable. So, it is `Dim a as Integer, b as Integer` and not `Dim a, b as Integer`. In the latter of the two cases `a` will be of `DataType` variant (and **not** as possibly expected `Integer`).

(2) To pass `arrays` in VBA from a procedure to a function you'll have to pass it `ByRef`. As such, there is no need to created a second or third `array` (such as `pll()` or `fix()`).

(3) There is a VBA command `Fix`. Hence, you cannot use it for a variable.

Let me know if the above helped or if you require more background or a slight adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

you're tagging both "VBA" and "Visual Studio" but what follows is for VBA only

as to your very code I made it work (meaning it run to the end with no errors) only by substituting `fix` with `fixed`, since my Excel VBA "complier" throws a "Syntax error" message due to the existence of the "FIX()" VBA function.

so, after that substitution `Function se` was called and it returned an integer array with no problems.

but it didn't do what you stated as its due i.e.: "return the passed array in ascending order".

also, both your variable declaration and your input procedure would allow for strings to be passed.

so here follow my proposal to have your code do what you said you need ("return the passed array in ascending order") with a more robust input procedure

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim pl() As Integer, pll() As Integer

    pl = TryConvertToInt(Split(InputBox("insert numbers (separated by space):")))

    pll = se(pl)

End Sub


Function TryConvertToInt(arr As Variant) As Integer()
Dim i As Long, n As Long
ReDim myint(1 To UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1) As Integer

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If IsNumeric(arr(i)) And arr(i) <> 0 Then
        n = n + 1
        myint(n) = CInt(arr(i))
    End If
Next i
ReDim Preserve myint(1 To n) As Integer

TryConvertToInt = myint
End Function


Function se(pol() As Integer) As Integer()

'adapted from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/133135

    Dim Temp As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NoExchanges As Boolean

    Dim fixed() As Integer
    ReDim fixed(1 To UBound(pol) - LBound(pol) + 1)

    fixed = pol
    ' Loop until no more "exchanges" are made.
    Do
        NoExchanges = True

        ' Loop through each element in the array.
'        For i = 1 To UBound(pol) - 1
        For i = LBound(fixed) To UBound(fixed) - 1

            ' If the element is greater than the element following it, exchange the two elements.
            If fixed(i) > fixed(i + 1) Then
                NoExchanges = False
                Temp = fixed(i)
                fixed(i) = fixed(i + 1)
                fixed(i + 1) = Temp
            End If
        Next i
    Loop While Not (NoExchanges)

    se = fixed

End Function
```

as you can see:

- the `main` sub is now very simple and reduced to three statements

  - the first being the variables declarations one
  - the second statements nests three calls:

    - the call to `InpuBox` function where the user is asked to input all wanted numbers separated by spaces (and no need to have a zero to close the sequence)
    - the call to `Split` function to have it parse the input string into a strings array made of as many strings as input ones separated by spaces
    - the call to `TryConvertToInt` function that takes care of analyzing the strings array and convert it to an integer array, allowing only numbers other than zeros
  - the third statement calls `se` function and puts its return integer array into `pll` integer array
- the `se` function has a sorting algorithm derived from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/133135, only adapted to handle integer arrays only.

with such a structure you can now be more effective in coding along since you can concentrate on the `main` sub to do "main" works (do this, do that, ...) via calls to specific subs and/or functions.

this leaving "non-main" works into specific subs or functions where to concentrate on for specific purpose only: for instance you may want to customize the `TryConvertToInt` function for more detailed filtering actions